# Given 2 hot air balloons, one ten times bigger then the other, which one will float for longer, by how much and why?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, temperature, fluid-statics, thermal-conductivity

We assume that the balloons are perfect spheres. The temperature inside both is $120^\circ \; C$. Ambient temperature is $20^\circ \; C $ and ambient pressure equals the atmospheric pressure.

I don't know what the heat diffusion coefficient should be, but I have calculated, using Newton's law of cooling, the k value of `k = 0.00057261016` per square meter. I've reached this numbers by Googling around, and substituting into the formula `T(t) = Tenv + (Tinitial - Tenv) * e^(-kt)`. From what I have found, a hot air balloon stays up for 60 minutes. As such:

```
T(60) = 20.1 -> since takes 60 minutes for the the balloons to reach ambient temperature of 20 celsius
T(60)  = 20 + (120 - 20)* e^(-60k)  
...
k = 0.115129
```

Given the radius of the sphere is 4m, area 201.06 square meters:

```
0.115129 / 201.06 = 0.00057261016 per square meter - which hopefully is correct reasoning and a realistic number,  please correct me if not
```

So how to figure out how much longer a balloon with 10x the radius will stay up, if it indeed does(not rely sure). And how to reach that by calculation not just by intuition?

And also about forming the right intuition, how to think this relation between **volume, area and floating time(im assuming that the floating condition can be expressed by temperature in balloon is higher then environment temperature)** between different balloons.

Take this cases (this are not balloons, just hypothetical oversimplified shapes (can be 3d volumetric fractals if you dont like the unrealistic volume-area ratio you see below))

```
case 1:
shape1 ( volume = 1, area = 1, time = 1)
shape2 ( volume = 1, area = 1, time = 1)
```

Makes sense for shape1 and shape2 to have take same time to cool off - are identical - as such float for the same amount of time = 1.

```
case 2:
shape1 ( volume = 2, area = 2, time = ?)
shape2 ( volume = 2, area = 2, time = ?)
```

How will doubling both area and volume should affect the cooling time? Will time be exactly like in case1? time = 1? I would say yes but im not sure.

```
case 3:
shape1 ( volume = 1, area = 1, time = 1)
shape2 ( volume = 1, area = 2, time = 0.5)
```

Here I would say it takes 2 times faster (time = 0.5) to cool the same amount hot air (volume = 1) if we double the area (area = 2) and keep everything else the same.

```
case 4:
shape1 ( volume = 1, area = 1, time = 1)
shape2 ( volume = 2, area = 1, time = 2 ?)
```

In this case, for shape2 I would say it takes 2 times longer for the double amount of air to cool trough the same surface area compared to shape1

Are my intuitions in the 4 cases presented correct? Please address the previous 2 questions also Thanks :)

Comment: Are you assuming the volumes of the balloons remain constant, i.e., are you considering them to be rigid spheres?

Comment: @BobD yes, rigid spheres.

Comment: The fact that the spheres are rigid and not actually balloons changes my answer. I have temporarily deleted it so I can edit it and repost

Answer (score 1):

I can't follow all your steps to answer each of your questions, but I believe all other things being equal the temperature of the air in the larger sphere should fall more slowly than that in the smaller sphere because of the lower surface area to volume ratio of the larger sphere. This ratio is inversely proportional to the radius. This is one of the reasons smaller planets cool faster than larger planets (source: Lunar and Planetary Institute).

However, you have indicated that you are considering rigid spheres. That means a drop in the temperature of the air within will have no effect on either the upward buoyant force nor the downward weight of the sphere. The spheres will continue to "float" when the temperature drops.

Rigid spheres mean the volume of the spheres are constant, the weight of the displaced ambient air remains the same, and the upward buoyant force on the spheres will be unchanged when the temperature of the air inside goes down. Moreover, the downward weight of the sphere (shell + enclosed air) will also be constant (the masses of the spheres are constant).

Bottom line: a drop in temperature changes neither the upward buoyant force nor the downward weight of the spheres, and the spheres will remain afloat. Assuming ideal gas behavior, the only effect of the temperature drop in the sphere is to reduce the pressure inside the sphere.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok thanks:) the planet comparison makes it very clear indeed - in fact im actually interested in comparing 2 zeppelins of different sizes - not spheres, but since that is a complicated shape i said a sphere since the principle should hold to a different geometry. Since a rigid frame zeppelin does not change in volume as it cools or heats up, then makes sense to have the requirement for spheres be rigid also. So now how can we calculate for how much longer this bigger sphere will remain in the air?

Comment: @AIon See my updated answer based on a closed rigid shell assumption.